# Find unresolved external symbol using similar project that builds fine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have two C projects that pull in the same library.

One project compiles and links fine, the other gets an "unresolved external reference" linker error for a symbol referenced inside a function which both projects call from the same static library.

As far as I can tell, all the linker and code generation properities of importance are equal between the two.

Is there a way to use the working project, to figure out where the linker in THAT project finds the symbol? I've been using trial and error, including more and more of the libraries from one project into the other with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I wanted! In the Project Properties, under Linker->Debugging, there is an option named "Generate Map File". This can be done on the command-line with /MAP.

The generated map file gets the same name as the project (by default) with .map as file extension. It is a text file containing, among other things, the library name where each symbol is defined.

Using the map file for my project that builds, I was able to quickly find the definition of the symbol missing from my broken project.